# Javascript replace two double quotes with single double quotes of Array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

CSV file data

```
"Name", "OfcLocation", "IPAddress", "Port" ,"Role"
"Tom", "USA",  "XX.XXX.X.XX", "4300", "Admin"
"Mark", "Spain", "XX.XXX.X.XX", "4080", "Limited"
"Jack", "Japan", "XX.XXX.X.XX", "9200", "Admin"
```

I am reading the CSV file. I use npm package [ngx-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-csv-parser) for reading csv file. After reading csv file it's return data as the following format.

```
const response:any[];


[""Name"", ""OfcLocation"", ""IPAddress"", ""Port"" ,""Role""],
[""Tom"", ""USA"",  ""XX.XXX.X.XX"", ""4300"", ""Admin"" ]
[ ""Mark"", ""Spain"", ""XX.XXX.X.XX"", ""4080"", ""Limited"" ]
[ ""Jack"", ""Japan"", ""XX.XXX.X.XX"", ""9200"", ""Admin"" ]
```

I tried to replace two double quotes with single quotes through

```
let jData = JSON.stringify(response).replace(/""/g,'"');
```

and again try to convert into JSON

```
let parseData = JSON.parse(jData);
```

getting error as **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON**.
Basically, I want data like this, after replace two double quotes with single quote

```
["Name", "OfcLocation", "IPAddress", "Port" ,"Role"],
["Tom", "USA",  "XX.XXX.X.XX", "4300", "Admin" ]
[ "Mark", "Spain", "XX.XXX.X.XX", "4080", "Limited" ]
[ "Jack", "Japan", "XX.XXX.X.XX", "9200", "Admin" ]
```

Comment: Just to confirm, its currently an array with arrays right and each value starts with `"` and ends with `"` ?

Comment: yes expected array item value should start with (single double quotes) `"` and end with `"`.

Comment: can you show the original CSV that produces this result?

Comment: can u plzz share ur csv file ?

Comment: @MuhammadFazeel I share the CSV data

Comment: did u try using header  to true in  ngxCsvParser.parse({header: true})????

Comment: yes I tried, it's not problem with header

Comment: I want to point out that your desired output is not valid JSON. Each row `[...]` is, but not the whole chunk. As @MuhammadFazeel mentioned, try `ngxCsvParser.parse({header: true})`. According to the documentation, it outputs a valid JSON object.

Comment: @ANJYR no the problem is the inconsistent whitespace around your fields or maybe that you have whitespace there in the first place, don't know this particular parser. imo. you can either fix that in your CSV (if possible) and check wether this fixes the problem or you need to strip the double quote at the start and end of a value.

Comment: download this csv file https://filebin.net/ifp9jrliv6tpx0wp and try it

Comment: @MuhammadFazeel this csv is working,

Answer (score 0):

I am Changing My Answer First U have to Stringify ur response and then u have to replace that string like this..

if stringify not working then change response to string like this
`` let string= `${your response data here}` `` 
and then replace

```js
let string = `[""Name"", ""OfcLocation"", ""IPAddress"", ""Port"" ,""Role""],[""Tom"", ""USA"",  ""XX.XXX.X.XX"", ""4300"", ""Admin"" ][ ""Mark"", ""Spain"", ""XX.XXX.X.XX"", ""4080"", ""Limited"" ][ ""Jack"", ""Japan"", ""XX.XXX.X.XX"", ""9200"", ""Admin"" ]`

let myString = string.replace(/""/g, '"');

console.log(myString)
```

Comment: that's correct, but csv file coming from some other application. so i can't change the format of csv

Comment: The scenario is, from some applications we will exporting data into CSV format. after that we will upload into our application and read it and do manipulation.

Comment: from application Web UI

Comment: can u share the format of data u r geting frm web UI???

Comment: It's already updated in question
`"Name", "OfcLocation", "IPAddress", "Port" ,"Role"
"Tom", "USA",  "XX.XXX.X.XX", "4300", "Admin"
"Mark", "Spain", "XX.XXX.X.XX", "4080", "Limited"
"Jack", "Japan", "XX.XXX.X.XX", "9200", "Admin"`

Comment: check Now i have change my answer

Answer (score -2):

When you get your response back as stringified json those quotes will be backslashed like this:

```
"[{\"Name\":\"OfcLocation\",\"IPAddress\":\"Port\"}]"
```

Are you saying that when you get your results back they look like this?
Which would seem odd.

```
"[{\"\"Name\"\":\"\"OfcLocation\"\",\"\"IPAddress\"\":\"\"Port\"\"}]"
```

Ok it might help to use a backslash before your quote like this.

```
response.replace(/\"\"/g,'"');
```

If that doesn't work then test your stringify method that it is indeed returning a valid string.

You can try validating your json here:

- https://jsonlint.com/